# R Sweave: digits number in xtable of prop.table

Tags: r, digits, xtable

I'm making an `xtableFtable` on R Sweave and can't find a way to suppress the digits with this code. What I am doing false? I've read that it can happen if your values aren't numeric but factor or character, but is `prop.table` making them non-numeric? I'm lost...

```
library(xtable)
a <- ftable(prop.table(table(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$hp), margin=2)*100)
b <- xtableFtable(a, method = "compact", digits = 0)
print.xtableFtable(b, rotate.colnames = TRUE)
```

I've already tried with `digits=c(0,0,0,0...)` too.

Comment: Do you mean trying `b <- xtableFtable(digits=0, a, method = "compact")` or do you mean `digits=4` as default in the options of the sweave or LaTeX file?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem! If you write that as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `options(digits)` to control how many digits will print. Try something like `options(digits = 4)` as the first line of your code (change `4` to whatever value you want between `1` and `22`). See `?options` for more information.

Or round the values before printing

```
a = round(ftable(prop.table(table(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$hp), margin=2)*100), 2)
b = xtableFtable(a, method = "compact")
print.xtableFtable(b, rotate.colnames = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "digits" argument to `xtableFtable` seems to be unimplemented (as of my version, which is 1.8.3), since after playing around with it for half an hour nothing seems to make any difference.

There's a hint to this effect in the function documentation:

> It is not recommended that users change the values of `align`, `digits` or `align`. First of all, alternative values have not been tested. Secondly, it is most likely that to determine appropriate values for these arguments, users will have to investigate the code for `xtableFtable` and/or `print.xtableFtable`.

It's probably just carried over from the `xtable` function (on which `xtableFtable` is surely based) as a TODO which the maintainer hasn't gotten around to yet.